# I don't know about setJarByClass(job) in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop

I have a 2 questions.

I'm doing mapreduce tutorial
[enter link description here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.2.4/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html)

I understand setJarByClass's role is to specify the location of the mapper class and reducer class.
When I run the Wordcount2 class **without job.setJarByClass(WordCount2.class)**, it's running correctly. So, I think if i don't specify it, Hadoop will do it automatically.

**And here is my question 1.** Is it correct? The guess that Hadoop do it automatically.

When I run the Wordcount2 class **with job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class)**, it's running correctly same as above case. What I expected was that the map and reduce functions of the wordcount class would be executed.

**And here is my question 2.** In this case, why running the code like Wordcount2 class?

Comment: I don't understand your second question

Answer (score 1):

That's to set the job driver entrypoint, not mappers and reducers... Jars can have multiple classes, so you need to set one class, otherwise I believe it takes the JAR given to `hadoop jar` command. But if there's no main entrypoint for the given JAR, and there's no `setJar` method call, it'll fail

That code also includes setMapperClass and setReducerClass (and combiner). Remove those if you actually wanted to test what's set automatically via the jar method